# Get Input from keyboard without waiting for input

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Functions like fgets() and getch() will wait for the user to enter input before continuing. What I want is this functionality: 
If the user presses 'x' a variable will begin decrementing, 'c' will cause the variable to begin incrementing.
The problem is the program halts when I try to get input. I want the variable to continue incrementing or decrementing and no 'freezing' while waiting for user input.

I am using visual studio 2008, writing a c console application.

Thanks!

Comment: Use _kbhit(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a special CONSOLE INPUT/OUTPUT library like NCURSES or Borland's CONIO to do that. Can't do it with standard C library.

If you are using Windows exclusively, take a look at [Windows Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Maybe its overkill, but he could use threads to simulate this behavior as well.